# Opening to Page in PDF via VBA - Refrencing a field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've got a PDF file that is full of part numbers, inwhich fall under 'Standards'. I have created a database, and a field called Page Number. Now my code below opens a PDF to the specified page, but after creating my field that has page numbers, instead of specifying an actually page number, I want it to read the field and use that page number as reference.
Any help regarding this issue would be great. My code is all follows:

```
Private Sub ViewStandard_Click()

'open pdf at page #
  Dim pageNum As String
  Dim fileloc As String
  Dim bookmark As String

  pageNum = Me.Page
  fileloc =
  bookmark = 

  pat1 = """C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"""

  pat2 = "/A ""page=pageNum"""

  pat3 = """fileloc"""

  Shell pat1 & " " & pat2 & " " & pat3, vbNormalFocus

  'fileloc = location of pdf
  'bookmark = fileloc & pagenum

End Sub
```

Please note, my access knowledge is fairly limited and I had a good amount of assistance from a fellow co-worker in starting this. So I'm not really sure how the String commands work. Also, I'm not really sure how to code in the fileloc/bookmark(PDF page) and pagenum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand where you're getting the values for pageNum and fileloc.  Your code is apparently for the click event of a command button.  In that case, `Me.Page` refers to a property of the form.  Here's what Access' help has to say about it:

*The **Page** property specifies the current page number when a form or report is being printed. Read/write **Long**.*

If this is a bound form, and its Record Source includes fields for Page_Number and File_Location, I think you should add bound text box controls (txtPageNumber and txtFileLocation) for those fields.  Then you can refer to those values (from the currently displayed record) when you build the string you will feed to Shell.

```
Private Sub ViewStandard_Click()
    Dim strReader As String
    Dim strShell As String

    strReader = "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"
    strShell = """" & strReader & """ /A ""page=" & Me.txtPageNumber & """ """ & _
        Me.txtFileLocation & """"
    Debug.Print "strShell: " & strShell 
    Shell strShell, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

I'm not certain I got all the quote marks correct.  `Debug.Print` will allow you to view the completed string you're asking Shell to execute.  You can copy that string from the Immediate Window and paste it into a command prompt window to test it, and adjust as needed.

Also, in your earlier question, you were given suggestions for alternatives to Shell.  I encourage you to make the time to look into them.

Comment: Thanks a ton HansUp. I've got everything working flawlessly now!

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Database

Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, _
ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Private Const SW_SHOWNORMAL As Long = 1
Private Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED As Long = 3


Private Sub Command0_Click()
    ShellExecute 0, "Open", "C:\Users\hp\Documents\Office Work\Shruti\DownloadForm16.pdf", vbNullString, "C:\", SW_SHOWNORMAL
End Sub
```